# SliderMenu feature in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard, slider

[SliderMenu in Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RQ7hW5Jnu0)

I can't do something similar to this video, the animation doesn't stop and the menu always flashes. Here's my XAML:

```xaml
<StackPanel.Style>
    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" 
                              From="-70,0,0,0" To="15,0,15,0" 
                              DecelerationRatio=".8" Duration="0:0:0.7"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" 
                              From="15,0,15,0" To="-70,0,0,0" 
                              DecelerationRatio=".8" Duration="0:0:0.7"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</StackPanel.Style>
```

What's the problem with it?

Comment: It's a 33 minute video and it's in Turkish. You might want to mention time in the video to skip to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flickering is happening because as soon as the StackPanel starts animating, it moves itself out of the way (of the mouse cursor), causing the other animation to start. I don't see you full code, so here are a couple of pointers to improve your code.

1. Make sure the entire menu is hittest-visible (e.g. by setting a background)
2. Don't use two triggers, use one trigger with enter and exit-triggers
3. Avoid the margin on the left - it can cause the same kind of flickering again.

```xaml
<StackPanel Background="Blue" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <StackPanel.Style>
        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-70,0,0,0"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" 
                                  From="-70,0,0,0" To="0,0,0,0" 
                                  DecelerationRatio=".8" Duration="0:0:0.7"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" 
                                  From="0,0,0,0" To="-70,0,0,0" 
                                  DecelerationRatio=".8" Duration="0:0:0.7"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Style>
    <Button Width="100" Height="25"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I forget post the margin of Image(ICON), when I delete it, it will work,

Comment: @You-shengLiang You should still use a single Trigger instead of two EventTriggers.